# Problems in converting ".to_datetime" in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I have the following list:

```
l = [<div class="date">8 December 2004</div>,
 <div class="date">6 December 2004</div>,
 <div class="date">18 October 2004</div>,
 <div class="date">9 October 2004</div>,
 <div class="date">8 August 2004</div>,
 <div class="date">18 June 2004</div>,
 <div class="date">23 December 2005</div>,
 <div class="date">19 December 2005</div>,
 <div class="date">19 December 2005</div>,
 <div class="date">15 December 2005</div>]
```

I would like to convert it into a dataframe with a `Date` column in a `to.datetime` format.

I tried many solutions (see one below) but I couln't get my head around it.

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame({'Date':l}), format = '%d %B %Y')
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What is inside your list? strings? Please provide an unambiguous valid python object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract text inside tags by `BeautifulSoup` and then convert to datetimes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[ BeautifulSoup(x, features="lxml").text for x in l]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%d %B %Y')
print (df)
        Date
0 2004-12-08
1 2004-12-06
2 2004-10-18
3 2004-10-09
4 2004-08-08
5 2004-06-18
6 2005-12-23
7 2005-12-19
8 2005-12-19
9 2005-12-15
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're scraping it with `BeautifulSoup`, you should be able to just call the following for your series.

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([e.text for e in l]))
```

But if it's actually a string already, you'll need to extract the date out of the `div`s. Then you might want something like to remove the `div` tags:

```
import re
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([re.sub(r'<\/?div.*?>', '', s) for s in l]))
```

Alternatively, you could extract the dates themselves using a regular expression perhaps like `\d{1,2} \w+ \d{4}`.

Nb that compilation is *not* necessary. For short scripts like most Pandas scripts, regular expressions are compiled and cached, according to the `re` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).

> The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to `re.compile()` and the module-level matching functions are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.

Comment: thanks a lot! I rewarded the fastest answer but I learnt a great deal from either!